# Getting Error ArrayList in java.util does not take parameters

Tags: java, arraylist

I've made a class "Student" now I'm trying to store my Student objects in an ArrayList but I'm getting error while compiling that ArrayList does not take accepts parameters. I've checked my code many time but unable to find the problem.

[image: Error Picture]

My student class is this

```
public class Student
{
//declaring variables 
private int rollNumber ;
private String name ;


//a counter for counting how many students or objects are declaired yet
public static int studentCount = 0;
public static int getStudentCount()
{
    return studentCount;
}


//getters for both variables
public int getRollNumber()
{
    return rollNumber;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}


//setters for both variables 
public void setRollNumber(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        this.rollNumber = x;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Roll Number Value");
    }
}
public void setName(String someName)
{
    this.name = someName;
}


//default constructor
public Student()
{
    setName("Please Enter A Name");
    this.rollNumber = 0;
    studentCount +=1;
}


//parameterized constructor
public Student(String name, int x)
{
    setName(name);
    setRollNumber(x);
    studentCount += 1;
}


//copy constructor
public Student(Student s)
{
    setName(s.name);
    setRollNumber(s.rollNumber);
    studentCount +=1;
}

//defining an print method 
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Student Name = " + name + "______Roll Number = " + rollNumber);
}
}
```

and the class in which i'm implimenting it is as follows

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList
{
    public static void main (String[] anyString)
{
    //Creating Some student objects
    Student s1 = new Student("Ammar" , 1);
    Student s2 = new Student("Ahmad" , 2);
    Student s3 = new Student("Arslan", 3);


    //Creating an arraylist
    ArrayList<Student> someList= new ArrayList<Student>();


    //checking if our Array List is empty or not 
    boolean empty = someList.isEmpty();
    if (empty == true)
        System.out.println("ArrayList is Empty \n\n");


    //adding our student class objects to our arraylist
    someList.add(s1);
    someList.add(s2);
    someList.add(s3);


    //checking if arraylist is empty or not 
    empty = someList.isEmpty();
    if (empty == true)
        System.out.println("ArrayList is Empty");
    else
    //counting total members in a list 
    System.out.println("Our ArrayList someList have a total of " +someList.size() + " Members \n\n");


    //geting back objects from arraylist or extractin them from list 
    //we will display our objects to console one by one 
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.size() ; i++)
    {
        Student one = someList.get(i);
        one.print();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `public class ArrayList`...

Comment: The `ArrayList` class you've created doesn't take type parameters, it's not a generic class.  (Hint: Don't give things names that already belong to other things.)

Comment: Yo man, I heard you liked `ArrayList`s. So I put an `ArrayList` in your `ArrayList` so the compiler gets confused.

Comment: please guide me how can i declare a arraylist to add my student class objects in it ?? 
can u give me a little code example ?

Comment: Ammar - the basic problem is, that you've named your class ArrayList, which overseeds the java.util.ArrayList you want to use. So - the best option is - rename your class to something else (unique). If you insist to keep the class name, you can refer the java.utilArrayList by the whole class name (including the package)

Comment: my question is marked as duplicate while its not duplicate i'm getting a different type of error that is mentioned in other question..if it is same than still i'm unable to understand my problem in that question..  please guide me according to my question. 
thanks

Comment: You have to rename your class (and the source file to match the new name). As other people already has suggested, you have a naming conflict with an already existing class. Your question is a duplicate as the reason (the problem) is the same.

Comment: @GabrielVince 
Thanks for answer..
I've use the follwing code to declare an array list 
ArrayList<Student> someList= new ArrayList<Student>()
what i should change to make it effecte lease mention.... thanks :)

Comment: @AmmarAhmed: There's no simpler way to explain this.  You have *named your own class* `ArrayList`.  So you're not declaring a normal `ArrayList`, you're declaring *your custom* `ArrayList`.  Which doesn't have a type parameter.  The solution is to *not name your class `ArrayList`*.

Comment: hmm.... os i have to write it like this  someList= new ArrayList(); ??

Comment: @AmmarAhmed: If you want to declare an instance of *your* `ArrayList`, sure.  But I'm *fairly certain* that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @David bro all i want is to declare a simple arraylist which can store my student calss objects plz guide me...

Comment: I too like the solution that JynXXedRabbitFoot gives in his/her answer. If you don’t understand it, keep thinking until you do. If you don’t like it after you have understood it, you may use `java.util.ArrayList<Student> someList= new java.util.ArrayList<Student>();` as @GabrielVince has tried eagerly to explain. :-)

Comment: @AmmarAhmed: Oh for crying out loud.  We've been explaining it to you, but we can't understand it *for you*.  Read this ***very carefully***:  The. Solution. Is. To. Rename. Your. Class.

Comment: For the duplicate: Yes, in that other question the *symptom* is different. As has been said, the *problem* is the same and therefore also the *best solution* is the same, only the class name causing the problem being another class name.

Comment: ok ok ..i've understood... i've solved my problem ..

Comment: thanks everyone :) 
and plz dont mind i'm new to programming so ... :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Cleaned up and renamed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student
{
  String name;

  int id;

  public Student(String name, int id)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }

  public static void main(String[] anyString)
  {
    // Creating Some student objects
    Student s1 = new Student("Ammar", 1);
    Student s2 = new Student("Ahmad", 2);
    Student s3 = new Student("Arslan", 3);

    // Creating an arraylist
    ArrayList<Student> someList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    // checking if our Array List is empty or not
    boolean empty = someList.isEmpty();
    if (empty == true)
      System.out.println("ArrayList is Empty \n\n");

    // adding our student class objects to our arraylist
    someList.add(s1);
    someList.add(s2);
    someList.add(s3);

    // checking if arraylist is empty or not
    if (someList.isEmpty())
      System.out.println("ArrayList is Empty");
    else
      // counting total members in a list
      System.out.printf("Our ArrayList someList has a total of %d Members \n\n",
          someList.size());

    // geting back objects from arraylist or extracting them from list
    // we will display our objects to console one by one
    for (Student student : someList)
    {
      System.out.println(student);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Student [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: well - we wanted Ammar to find it by himself, he would learn a lot by himself :)

Comment: @GabrielVince brother... true..i also want to leanr it but  i'm stick to this since two hours know :P 
i just want to know what i have to change in 

ArrayList<Student> someList = new ArrayList<Student>();

if you suggest a change i'll be very thankfull :)

Comment: @AmmarAhmed The code I posted is what your code should be unless you were trying to implement your own `ArrayList`. Try it, pay attention to the differences.

Comment: @AmmarAhmed did you try it? Did it answer your question? Will you accept it as the answer?

Comment: yap bro...i've understood it completly..
i've named my class which is created for practice as "ArrayList" while i want to use (java.util), package to use ArrayList class in that packages.. 
so when i tried to create object using that ArrayList in java.util package compiler was considering my own ArrayList class. i've renamed it now :) 
remaining code was perfect :) 
sorry for disturbing all of you :) 
thansk Everyone :)

Comment: Great, glad to be of help, To accept an answer, choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.